# Optimum point of $f(s) = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{ \exp(-s) y \cos(ky)}{s^2+y^2} \,dy $

Tags: integration, optimization, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, numerical-optimization

Is it possible to find optimum point for the following function f(s) (i.e. $df/ds=0$):
$$
f(s) =  s e^{-s} \int_0^{a} \frac{  y \cos(\frac{\pi}{a} y)}{s^2+y^2} \,dy
$$
or
$$
f(s) =  s e^{-s} \int_0^{a/2} \frac{ y \cos(\frac{\pi}{a} y)}{s^2+y^2} \,dy
$$

Comment: Do you mean $e^{-sy}$ or can $e^{-s}$ be factored out of the integral?

Comment: It can be factored out.

Comment: you first would have to solve the integral, otherwise you can only get a numerical solution. And $exp^{-s}$ is probably wrong, you probably mean $\exp{\left(-s\right)}$.